# Largest number containing every possible $2$-digit string only once?

Tags: sequences-and-series, decimal-expansion

How can I easily find the largest number such that every $2$-digit string ($00, 01, 02,...)$ occurs only once (strings can share the same digit, eg. $104507$ contains the strings $45$ and $50$). I do not know where to start to find this number ($99989796959493929190.........09080706050403020100$) contains the strings $99$ and $90$ twice so concatenating all the strings from $00$ to $99$ won't work.

The largest number with every one digit string occurring only once is $9876543210$. Can someone help or explain how this number is impossible to find. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They keyword search you want is 'De Bruijn sequences' - which are quite fascinating!

For your example, the sequence you want is:

99897969594939291908878685848382818077675747372717066564636261605545352515044342414033231302212011009

For an alphabet of $k$ characters (in your case, $10$), any sequence containing all sub-sequences of length $n$ (in your case, $2$) must be at least $k^n + (n-1)$ digits; and a De Bruijn sequence, with the left-most $n-1$ appended to at the right end, has exactly that length.

I like the way De Bruijn sequences connect what seems like a combinatorial problem with a graph theory problem - see the Wikipedia page on the subject. Enjoy!

Comment: Interesting! Is this complicated to do for larger numbers, for instance finding the largest number such every $5$-digit string occurs only once?

Comment: Check out the python algorithm at the Wikipedia page. The resulting string would be produced by de_bruijn('9876543210', 5), and would have length 10^5 (so it's quite large, for a number!), but not particularly complex to generate.

Comment: Um, I don't see where 09 occurs.

Comment: Also, to have 100 two character strings won't it need exactly 101 digits? 100 first of two digits and a final last of two digits.

Comment: @fleablood - you are correct! The De Bruijn sequence 'loops' to create create all sequences, so actually it requires a $k^n + n-1$ digits... I will amend my post

Comment: I think this works if you put a 9 at the very end.  The first 19 digits are the largest they can be so any other will be smaller. With that start anywhere you put the 9 will not allow any digit after it, so it must go at the end.

Comment: @fleablood - A De Bruijn sequence, when thought of as a graphing problem, is about a cycle through a graph with $k^n$ nodes; so for the OP's problem, we can just tack on the leftmost 'n-1' elements of the sequence to represent this looping.

Comment: Makes sense.  It's interesting that once you start it's self determining.